# Cannot see or classify weighed overlay or weighted sum rasters using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, classification, overlay, unique-value

I ran weighed overlay and weighed sum on a suitability analysis in a model. neighther one is visible when added to display. The weighed sum values are also suspect (first pic). I go to properties, symbology and when I go to classify I get Error 1 (2nd pic) encountered an improper argument -failed to classify too many unique values, then when I try to classify I get error 2 (3rd pic). I have added statistics to both, it has not helped.

[image: error 0]

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

Comment: My guess is that your raster has values at the extreme end of float 32's  capabilities -1.79 e (+-) 308.  Perhaps they are NaNs / Null Values that were set as those extreme values by the model?  Poor Man's way of solving this for graphing purposes would to clip color scale negative and positive above and below those values respectively.  Looks like you attempted that in the screenshot you shared?  Was the second screen shot using the weighted values?  Because a glimpse of the color scale called "value" next to "127" indicates that you were using "suitable_wsum".(?)  try on the weighted.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, I am not sure why the values are so extreme. Both the v

Comment: sorry got cut off. The second snapshot was the attempt to switch to the classifed display of the weighed_ov (overlay) raster. I got extreme numbers with raster calculator also. How do I clip the values?  I was hoping to be able to get to the classify menu to  try to adjust it.